# Dictionary comprehensions синтаксис python

Tags: python, словари, dict, syntax

Допустим, у меня появилось 2 списка, в одном лежат ключи, в другом их значения. Соответствие поиндексное (1:1,2:2)

```
keys = []
values = []
```

Мне при помощи генератора словарей нужно создать словарь, ключом которого является `keys[i]`, а значением `values[i]`.

Подскажите правильный синтаксис этого действия, всё, что пока получилось:

```py
{k:v for k in keys for v in values}
```

Oднако, данный синтаксис создаёт вложенный список и проходит по нему полностью.
Mогу ли я как-то осуществить синхронный забор данных из списков?

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}` или `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: Данное решение работает, вопрос закрывать не буду, чтобы была возможность его дополнять.

Comment: @MaxU Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12, да, пожалуй лучше не оставлять вопрос висящим без ответа

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В том случае если число элементов в `keys` и `values` совпадает можно воспользоваться встроенной функцией [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [1]: keys = list("abcd")

In [2]: values = [11,12,13,14]
```

dictionary comprehension:

```
In [3]: d = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}

In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 14}
```

dict() конструктор:

```
In [5]: d2 = dict(zip(keys, values))

In [6]: d2
Out[6]: {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 14}
```

если число элементов не совпадает, то не все элементы попадут в итоговый словарь:

```
In [14]: values = [11, 12, 13]

In [15]: keys
Out[15]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [16]: values
Out[16]: [11, 12, 13]

In [17]: d3 = dict(zip(keys, values))

In [18]: d3
Out[18]: {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}
```

ключ `d` не попал в словарь

```
In [19]: d4 = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}

In [20]: d4
Out[20]: {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13}
```

если в результирующем словаре должны быть все элементы, то можно воспользоваться [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
In [21]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [22]: d5 = dict(zip_longest(keys, values))

In [23]: d5
Out[23]: {'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': None}
#  NOTE:  ------------------------->  ^^^^^^^^
```